# Unable to strip invalid unicode characters java

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I have my data which needs to be cleaned up before further processing in various other applications. In this process one of the downstream applications only allows a certain range of Unicode characters. The following is the regex I'm using to strip out the invalid Unicode characters.

```
/[^\u0009\u000a\u000d\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]/
```

However, I'm still having issues getting the regex to work in Java. Is there a special way to treat the above regex, since it contains a range of Unicode characters?

UPDATE:
This is how I tested the same and didn't seem to get it to work with the way suggested by @Andreas :

```
public void testStripUnicode() {
        String doc = "{\"fields\":{\"field1\":\"unicode char '\\u000b'\",\"field2\":[\"unicode char '\\u0003'\"]}}";
        String stripped = DocumentCleaner.clean(doc);
        System.out.println(doc);
        System.out.println(stripped);
    }
```

doc

`{"fields":{"field1":"unicode char '\u000b'","field2":["unicode char '\u0003'"]}}`
stripped-doc

`{"fields":{"field1":"unicode char '\u000b'","field2":["unicode char '\u0003'"]}}`

Answer (score 0):

Should be fine, just drop the slashes `/` and double the backslashes `\`:

```
String regex = "[^\\u0009\\u000a\\u000d\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD]";
String stripped = value.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

Or if you do it repeatedly, you can parse the regular expression once, up front:

```
// Prepare regular expression
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\u0009\\u000a\\u000d\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD]");

// Use regular expression
String stripped = p.matcher(value).replaceAll("");
```

Comment: @AdiGuN that test string doesn't contain any of the characters that your regex would strip - the string literal `"\\u0003"` is the six characters backslash, u, 0003, not the single character U+0003. If you want to remove these escape sequences as well as the characters they represent then you'll need a different regex.

Comment: @IanRoberts Could you elaborate. The regex seem to contain a ^ in front of it, so \u0003 should be stripped right?

Comment: @AdiGuN No, your string contains the 6 characters `'\', 'u', '0', '0', '0', '3'`, **not** the single Unicode character [U+0003 (END OF TEXT)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0003/index.htm).

Comment: I see.  Can I test it out in another way? Before I apply this to my huge dataset

Comment: @AdiGuN Try it on a smaller subset of your huge dataset.

Comment: @Andreas another related question does java regex support unicode range in this case we seem to be using \\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD.

I'm wondering if that might be the reason why I'm still not able to strip the characters

Comment: @AdiGuN Yeah, it works. If you remove the `^`, it'll remove all characters except the bad ones. Your problem seems to be that your JSON string doesn't contain bad *characters*, but contain JSON escape sequences that you want to eliminate, such that when the JSON string is *parsed*, you don't end up with bad characters in the parsed data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90139/discussion-between-adi-gun-and-andreas).